# How to bind FileHelper.CSVEngine to BeforeWriteRecord event

Tags: c#, filehelpers

While exporting a data-table to CSV using the `FileHelpers.CsvEngine.DataTableToCsv`. I couldn't hook the "`BeforeWriteRecord`" event like I did for `FileHelperEngine`. Is there any possibility to hook operations in CSVEngine class.

Comment: As a temporary solution, I modified the CSVEngine.DataTableToCSV proc to accept a new parameter Func<object[],object[]> as a callback fucntion for BeforeWriteRecord like event.

Answer (score 0):

The `CSVEngine` class does not currently (version 2.9.9) support the `BeforeWriteRecord` event.  I think the reason is that the `BeforeWriteRecordEventArgs` expects a FileHelpers record class which is not relevant when exporting from a `DataTable`.

The code for `DataTableToCsv` is a simple static method so it would be easy to provide your own replacement.  The code is [here](http://filehelpers.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/filehelpers/trunk/FileHelpers/Engines/CsvEngine.cs?revision=942&view=markup) and quoted below:

```
    public static void DataTableToCsv(DataTable dt, string filename, CsvOptions options)
    {
        using (var fs = new StreamWriter(filename, false, options.Encoding, EngineBase.DefaultWriteBufferSize))
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                object[] fields = dr.ItemArray;
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                        fs.Write(options.Delimiter);
                    fs.Write(options.ValueToString(fields[i]));
                }
                fs.Write(StringHelper.NewLine);
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```